# app.get is undefined (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my `app.js` file I do the following...

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

Then in my `register.js` file I am using `get` to render a page in the following way...

```
var module = require('../app');

module.app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.jade', { title: 'register' });
});
```

But I get the error that `get cannot be used with app because it is undefined`

If I change my `get` function to the following, everything works fine...

```
exports.register = function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.jade', { title: 'register' });
};
```

and change my `app.js` to...

```
app.get('/register', reg.register);
```

... it will work.

But I want to be able to export `app` so I can use it in other routes. How do I properly export it?

**EDIT**

I just realized the proper way to to require the module is using `var app = require('./app');`.

The path I mentioned before is wrong.

But now I get an error `cannot find module ./app`, I have no idea why.

Comment: try to verify your folders structure you're importing '../app.js' so your app.js is supposedly  placed in a folder that contains a folder with register.js inside of it

Comment: @oneLeggedChicken My project folder contains and app.js file and a couple of other folders, one of them being a `routes` folder, inside the `routes` there is my file `register.js`. What would be the correct way to `require` then?... In other words `app.js` and `routes` are on the same level

Comment: ok i suppose by same level you mean in the same folder so it should be like this `var module = require('./app.js');`

Comment: @oneLeggedChicken no i tested it I believe my require statement is good, the problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only things assigned to `module.exports` are visible outside of that JavaScript file. In your case that is returned value of `express()`. There is no `module.app` exported. Also, stop using `module` as variable name, because its one of [the globals](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) injected to the JavaScript file.

Better do something more clear and hand control to server script, which in turn will call all required setup functions on server run:

Structure:

```
project
   |_controllers
   |   |_login.js
   |   |_register.js
   |_routes.js
   |_app.js
```

*controllers/login.js :*

```
/**
 * Login user.
 * @param req - express Request.
 * @param res - express Response.
 * @param next - calls next middleware.
 */
function login(req,res,next){
   res.send("Login!");
}

// exports
module.exports = login;
```

*controllers/register.js :*

```
/**
 * Register user.
 * @param req - express Request.
 * @param res - express Response.
 * @param next - calls next middleware.
 */
function login(req,res,next){
   res.send("Register!");
}

// exports
module.exports = register;
```

*routes.js*:

```
/**
 * routes module.
 */
var routes = {};

/**
 * Setup app routes.
 * @param app - Express app instance.
 */
routes.setup = function setup(app){
   app.post('/register',require('./controllers/register'));
   app.post('/login',require('./controllers/login'));
}

// exports
module.exports = routes;
```

*app.js:*

```
var express = require('express');
var routes= require('./routes');

// init app
var app = express();

// setup routes
routes.setup(app);

// start server
app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: So in my `./controllers/register` file, how would I use the `/register` POST function?

Comment: @Bolboa Updated in answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I wanna say is what `module.exports=...` and `exports.something=...` do. `module.exports` is the object that would be import after `require` it. Let's say there is a file named X.js :

```
var A = {
    name:'A'
};
module.exports = A;
```

Now we can import it in other file, suppose we have a file named Y.js :

```
var A = require('pathToX/X');
console.log(A.name);
```

So, in your code `module.exports = express();`, the object you've exported is the "express()" itself. Your should use it in other files (for example, your register.js file) in this way :

```
var module = require('../app');
module.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.jade', { title: 'register' });
});
```

That is, when you call `require('../app')`, what you got is the `express()`. So your code `module.app.get` is equals to `express().app.get`, of cause there is no `app` property in `express()`.

Besides, the `module` is predefined in node js, please don't use it as a variable name, you can change your `register.js` file to

```
var app = require('../app');
app.get('/register', function (req, res) {
    res.render('register.jade', { title: 'register' });
});
```

And this is true : `exports===module.exports`, so you did the right way to import register in your code `app.get('/register', reg.register);`.

One more thing, `exports={name:'A'}` is NOT equals to `module.exports={name:'A'}`, that is pretty straightforward, `exports` is just a variable link to `module.exports`, change the `exports` link itself won't change `module.exports`.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I have one question. I just realized that proper way to require the module is like `var app = require('./app');` but it says `cannot find module ./app`...any idea why?

Comment: Path, file name (*nix is case-sensitive) or privilege, I can not imagine other things would cause this error. What OS do you use? Would you mind upload the whole project to github or something like that to let us see the project?

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js, try something more like:

```
module.exports = {
    app: express()
}
```

Then when you do `var module = require('./app')`, `module` will contain an object which has an `app` property.

Note that I don't know what `express()` does, but I am assuming it is returning an object that has a `get()` function on it.

Comment: still tells me `app.get` is not a function

Comment: Things to check then:
 - Does the object returned by `express()` even have a `get()` function?
 - Is `app.js` in the parent directory of `register.js` like you're implying with the `require('../app')` call?

Comment: The app is in the parent dir so `require` is good, I've tested it. I assume that `express` does have a get function since Ive `app.get` within my `app.js` file and it works

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//app.js

var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express();


//register.js

var module = require('./app.js');

//var http   = require('http');
//var server =  http.createServer(module);


module.get('/register', function(req,res,next) {
    // body...
    console.log("register");

});

//server.listen(1338);
```